# Python: Modifying text file, deleting substring

Tags: python, replace, text-files

I have a text file which has a line like this -

```
time    time    B2CAT_INLET_T\CAN-Monitoring:1  B1CAT_MIDBED_T\CAN-Monitoring:1 B1CAT_INLET_T\CAN-Monitoring:1  B1CAT_OUTLET_T\CAN-Monitoring:1 time    APEPFRPP\CCP:1  KDFILRAW\CCP:1
```

When I read it using

```
lines = txtfile.readlines()
```

I get lines =

```
'time\ttime\tB2CAT_INLET_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\tB1CAT_MIDBED_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\tB1CAT_INLET_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\tB1CAT_OUTLET_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\ttime\tAPEPFRPP\\CCP:1\tKDFILRAW\\CCP:1\t\t'
```

So the '\' show as 'double \' and the tab shows as '\t'

From this I want to delete all instances of '\CAN-Monitoring:1' and '\CCP:1' and preserve the tabs as they are.

I have a code that walks through each element of 'lines' and gets index of each 'double \' and '\t'

Then I tried to use lines.replace(index of 'double \':index of '\t','')

But this does not seem to work as I want.

Following is my code so far:

```
# Reading from text file

    txtfile = open('filename.txt', 'r')
    lines = txtfile.readlines()
    textToModify = lines

# This gives indices of all '\\' and '\t'

doubleslash = []
tab = []

for i, item in enumerate(textToModify):
    if textToModify[i] == '\\':
        doubleslash.append(i)

for i, item in enumerate(textToModify):
    if textToModify[i] == '\t':
        tab.append(i)


# Should find text beginning with '\\' until '\t' only

itemSlashBegin = []
itemTabBegin = []

for itemSlash in doubleslash:
    for itemTab in tab:
        if itemSlash < itemTab:
            break
    itemSlashBegin.append(itemSlash)
    itemTabBegin.append(itemTab)

# Trying to replace '\\'text'\t' in the original text

for i,item in enumerate(itemSlashBegin):
    ModifiedTxt = textToModify.replace([item:itemTabBegin[i]],"")
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way too; but I cannot find it.

Please give me some solution.

Thank you

R

Comment: post the  expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to import anything then use this

```
    f = 'time\ttime\tB2CAT_INLET_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\tB1CAT_MIDBED_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\tB1CAT_INLET_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\tB1CAT_OUTLET_T\\CAN-Monitoring:1\ttime\tAPEPFRPP\\CCP:1\tKDFILRAW\\CCP:1\t\t'

    s= ('\CAN-Monitoring:1','\CCP:1')
    for i in s:
        f=f.replace(i, '')

   print(f)

time    time    B2CAT_INLET_T   B1CAT_MIDBED_T  B1CAT_INLET_T   B1CAT_OUTLET_T  time    APEPFRPP    KDFILRAW
```

Comment: Would not that introduce a space where the substrings were replaced?

Comment: It does not because This is what the string looks like after removing those two substrings:
f
'time\ttime\tB2CAT_INLET_T\tB1CAT_MIDBED_T\tB1CAT_INLET_T\tB1CAT_OUTLET_T\ttime\tAPEPFRPP\tKDFILRAW\t\t''''

('' means no space. IF it was ' ' then that will replace with space.)

Comment: Please consider voting the answer if it helped heeh.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `re.sub` here:

```
out = re.sub(r'\\CAN-Monitoring:1|\\CCP:1', '', inp)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
time    time    B2CAT_INLET_T   B1CAT_MIDBED_T  B1CAT_INLET_T   B1CAT_OUTLET_T  time    APEPFRPP    KDFILRAW
```

Note that double backslash and `\t` are simply how a literal backslash and tab character are represented in a Python string.